# Can I set a link on my Facebook app to private message my business page?

Tags: messaging, fan-page, private-messaging

I've been asked to set-up an app for my business' Fan Page to show vacancies that we have in the company to try so that we can get applications through FB. Is there a way to set a link that directs users to message our Fan page? 
The bosses specifically want the applicants to go through facebook instead of just setting up a link to our regular email address as they want to be able to monitor the enquires we get through FB.

There's a lot of information about sending messages TO fans, but I can't a reference to being able to set a permission that would take a user to their compose message screen where the recipient would be our fan page.

If it can't be done, it can't be done, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about automating the Facebook Messaging Service but you can set up applications on your business fan page to collect Job Inquiries.

Are you using any Facebook Applications yet?

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, for delay in returning to this, the FB app got put on hold.

We're currently just using a Google Map app for our establishment - the HR department wants more control over over the job enquiries than Facebook would actually allow (hence asking for a purpose built one as opposed to the professionally done ones). From what I can ascertain, they're looking for the enquiries to be sent through Facebook to our Fan Page...so that they can then get a look at the applicants' profiles?